# View not rendering with data

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections

js app that is not displaying what it should.

Here's the app: http://jsfiddle.net/5sded/

It should be looping through the recipes, but instead it doesn't show anything. Here's the html:

```
<div id="recipes">
        <div class="recipeContainer">
            <img src="img/placeholder.png"/>
            <ul>
                <li>Name</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script id="recipeTemplate" type="text/template">
            <img src="<%= image %>"/>
            <ul>
                <li><%= name %></li>
            </ul>
        </script>
</div>
```

There also isn't any errors popping up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 issue with your code..

First `backbone` has a **hard dependency** on `underscore`.

The order in which you load the library is important

```
---> Underscore

---> Backbone
```

Looks like you were loading backbone first.

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/5sded/1/)**

2nd issue is that you have this in your template  `<%= image %>`

Where as `image` attribute not available neither in the array of objects of the default attributes.

Replace that with `<%= url %>`  instead. That should get the code working.

Also I prefer passing the collection while initializing the view. This has nothing to do with the error though.

```
var recipesView = new RecipesView({
    collection : new Recipes(recipes)
});
```

Comment: Glad I could be of help :)